# Facebook PHP SDK: handling access token errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Reading the Facebook documentation on Access Tokens, it's a little unclear how to actually write the PHP code to handle them. Testing reveals a little, but I would like to do this correctly.

So, in my app, I use the Javascript SDK to login, and when that comes back, I make an Ajax call to save the access token. The server that handles that call converts that access token to a long-lived token, and stores it in our DB. So far so good.

But in the future calls to the PHP SDK, I want to handle the access token expiring, or the user invalidating the token. My basic SDK calls are like:

```
try
{
    $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $this->fbApp, 
                                             $access_token, . . .);
    $response = $this->fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

    // some processing here
}
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $ex) 
{
}
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $ex)
{
}
```

The documentation suggests that I catch exceptions via capturing "the error messages thrown by the API", and gives this information:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time SOME_TIME. The current unix time is SOME_TIME.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 190
  }
}
```

with my only method of determining whether the token expired or the user de-authorized the app being doing a string comparison on the error message, or looking at a subcode (which, of course, are defined somewhere else. blech).

My main question is - will token errors always be thrown as FacebookResponseExceptions? I did a test with de-authorizing the app, and got that exception code of 190, and a message "Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application". Is there a way to get the subcode? Or do I just assume that an error code of 190 always means send them back through the login process?

And what about expired tokens? Tough to test that, will that throw an exception, or will the response from the SDK call be an error?

thanks...

Answer (score 2):

An OAuthException is a pretty sure indicator that either the token is not valid any more, or that you don’t have the permission necessary to perform the desired action – both cases in which you likely want to send the user through the login flow again.

For a list of some possible error codes, and general instructions on how you should generally handle the, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#errors

In case you run into such an OAuthException, you might want to debug the token that you have stored – that will tell you if it is still valid or not: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

And if it is, you might want to do a call for `/me/permissions` next, to find out what permissions the user has granted your app. You can also check for a specific permission via `/me/permissions/permission_name`.

Comment: That all sounds good.. but in PHP, I'm not getting an OAuthException, I'm getting a FacebookResponseException, at least in the case of someone deauthorizing the app. I don't know what I will get in the case of an expired token.

Comment: I was referring to the `"type": "OAuthException"` part of the exception you’re getting. To check for that should be safe (rather than doing string comparison on the `message` part, which might change at some point.)

Comment: Doh... Ok, go that. But... my app is going to run in the background as an auto posting app. If the token just expires because 60 days (or whatever random thing Facebook might decide to change it to), I'd like to be able to re-up the token there. If they de-authorize, that's different... so it would be nice to be able to tell the difference.